# AngularJS 2 row hover style

Tags: angular

I need to conditionally color some table rows based on hovering over another row.
So I think it is not possible with a css:hover class.

If my table contains 20 rows everything is ok. If there are more than 100 rows the coloring hangs.

I need to color the current hovered row (this can be done with pure css) and another row based on current row properties.

***diagnosis.component.ts***

```
...

@Component({
  selector: 'xxx',
  templateUrl: './diagnosis.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./diagnosis.component.scss'],
  animations: [routerTransition()],
  host: {'[@routerTransition]': ''}
})
export class DiagnosisComponent {

  private currentRow: any;
  private conjunctionRow: any;

  private tableData: TableData;

  ...

  onRowMouseEnter(row: any) {
    if (row.state === 1 || row.state === 2) {
      this.currentRow = row;
      this.conjunctionRow = this.tableData.content.find(cRow => cRow.state != row.state && cRow.sequenceNumber === row.sequenceNumber && cRow.eventCode === row.eventCode);
    }
  }

  onRowMouseLeave() {
    this.currentRow = null;
    this.conjunctionRow = null;
  }

}
```

***diagnosis.component.html***

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
<thead>
  ...
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let row of tableData?.content" (click)="onEventClicked(row)" (mouseenter)="onRowMouseEnter(row)" (mouseleave)="onRowMouseLeave()" [ngClass]="{'leave-event': (row === currentRow || row === conjunctionRow) && row.state === 2, 'rise-event': (row === currentRow || row === conjunctionRow) && row.state === 1}">
  ...
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I save the current hovered row in `onRowMouseEnter(row)` and process this variable in the ngClass condition.

However, using Angular2 `(mouseenter)` without any code in the function body lasts forever on the other hand using `onmouseenter="console.log('test');"` runs smoothy.

So using angular2 functions leeds to stumbling.

I know that `tableData.contant.find()` could be a problem but also commenting this line does not eliminate the stumbling.

Any ideas how to get this fixed?

Comment: Can you add more information, like the code of your component functions for example. would be helpful to know what your dynamically added css classes actually do. It would probably be more performant to not count on ngClass in this case, but to help you we need more of your code and your aims.